# javascript runtime on Opensuse

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, opensuse

I installed ruby on rails with the terminal of opensuse but I have a problem when I try to open the rails server. The terminal said : `Could not find a JavaScript runtime`, but it's running on Fedora, why not on OpenSuse? Could somebody help me?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to run rake db:create,  I went into the yast package manager and looked up javascript.  Install the JS package, everything seems to be working good now.